# How to reuse code in EDGE.js (nodeJS .NET packet)

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js

Ok, I'm currently working on UIAutomation with nodeJS and I'm using [EDGE.js](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/) node module. All works fine (wow), but I have an issue with code re-usability.

I have few mostly identical functions that consist from the same code for more than 50%. Of course I want to move this code to a single place, but problem is that this code placed in js comments (EDGE stuff).

How can I reuse my code to avoid repetitions in EDGE.js?

Yeah.. as a last resort I can put everything into one c# "program" and call different c# functions depending on arguments, but probably there is a way to keep several js functions? Thanks!

Here is an example of 2 functions. I want to keep different only "public async Task" part at the bottom of each block. Any ideas?

BTW: Any suggestions about C# code are also welcome! Cause I'm pretty sure, that it's total crap ^^

```
    getWindows: function() {

      /*
        using System;
        using System.Windows;
        using System.Windows.Automation;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

        public class myRect
        {
          public int width { get; set; }
          public int height { get; set; }
          public int top { get; set; }
          public int left { get; set; }
          public myRect( AutomationElement el ) {
            System.Windows.Rect r = (System.Windows.Rect)(
            el.GetCurrentPropertyValue(
              AutomationElement.BoundingRectangleProperty,
              true));
            width  = (int)r.Width;
            height = (int)r.Height;
            top    = (int)r.Top;
            left   = (int)r.Left;
          }
        }

        public class Winfo
        {
          public string name { get; set; }
          public string automationId { get; set; }
          public int processId { get; set; }
          public myRect window { get; set; }
          public myRect browser { get; set; }
        }


        public class Startup {

          private Winfo getWinInfo( AutomationElement el ) {
            if ( el == null ) return( null );
            Winfo winfo = new Winfo {
              name = el.Current.Name,
              automationId = el.Current.AutomationId,
              processId = el.Current.ProcessId,
              window = new myRect(el)
            };

            try {
              var tmpWeb = el
                .FindFirst( TreeScope.Descendants,
                  new PropertyCondition(
                    AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty,
                    "CefBrowserWindow") )
                .FindFirst( TreeScope.Descendants,
                  new PropertyCondition(
                    AutomationElement.NameProperty,
                    "Chrome Legacy Window"));

              winfo.browser = new myRect(tmpWeb);
            } catch { winfo.browser = null; }

            return(winfo);
          }

          public async Task<object> Invoke(dynamic input) {
            var els = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll(
              TreeScope.Children,
              Condition.TrueCondition);

            List<Winfo> windowList = new List<Winfo>{};
            bool all;
            try { all = (bool)input.all; } catch { all = false; };

            foreach (AutomationElement el in els) {
              Winfo winfo = getWinInfo(el);
              if ((winfo!=null) && (all || (winfo.browser!=null))) {
                windowList.Add( winfo );
              }
            }
            return(windowList);
          }
        }
       */
    }
```

And another one

```
    waitWindow: function() {

      /*
        using System;
        using System.Windows;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.Windows.Automation;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;
        using System.Threading;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

        public class myRect {
          public int width { get; set; }
          public int height { get; set; }
          public int top { get; set; }
          public int left { get; set; }
          public myRect( AutomationElement el ) {
            System.Windows.Rect r = (System.Windows.Rect)(
            el.GetCurrentPropertyValue(
              AutomationElement.BoundingRectangleProperty,
              true));
            width  = (int)r.Width;
            height = (int)r.Height;
            top    = (int)r.Top;
            left   = (int)r.Left;
          }
        }

        public class Winfo
        {
          public string name { get; set; }
          public string automationId { get; set; }
          public int processId { get; set; }
          public myRect window { get; set; }
          public myRect browser { get; set; }
        }

        public class Startup {
          private static AutoResetEvent waitHandle;

          private Winfo getWinInfo( AutomationElement el ) {
            if ( el == null ) return( null );
            Winfo winfo = new Winfo {
              name = el.Current.Name,
              automationId = el.Current.AutomationId,
              processId = el.Current.ProcessId,
              window = new myRect(el)
            };

            try {
              var tmpWeb = el
                .FindFirst( TreeScope.Descendants,
                  new PropertyCondition(
                    AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty,
                    "CefBrowserWindow") )
                .FindFirst( TreeScope.Descendants,
                  new PropertyCondition(
                    AutomationElement.NameProperty,
                    "Chrome Legacy Window"));

              winfo.browser = new myRect(tmpWeb);
            } catch { winfo.browser = null; }

            return(winfo);
          }

          public async Task<object> Invoke(dynamic input) {

            int t;
            try { t = (int)input.timeout; } catch { t = 0; };
            string wname;
            try { wname = (string)input.name; } catch { wname = ""; };

            AutomationElement el = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(
              TreeScope.Children,
              new PropertyCondition( AutomationElement.NameProperty, wname ));

            if ( el == null ) {
              waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
              Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(
                WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent,
                AutomationElement.RootElement,
                TreeScope.Children,
                (sender, e) => {
                  var obj = sender as AutomationElement;
                  if (obj.Current.Name == wname) {
                    el = obj;
                    waitHandle.Set();
                  }
                }
              );

              waitHandle.WaitOne(t);
              Automation.RemoveAllEventHandlers();
            }

            return( getWinInfo(el) );
          }
        }
       */
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the reusable C# code into separate multi-line javascript strings, using the same technique that edgejs uses.
Below is a simple example where a function has been broken into two separate variables, Line1 and Line2. You could split your code into multiple functions/variables that contains the re-usable code and then build your code by concatenating the individual bits.

```
var edge = require('edge');

function getMultilineString(fn){
    return (fn).toString().match(/[^]*\/\*([^]*)\*\/\}$/)[1];
}
var line1 = getMultilineString(function () {/*
    async (input) => {        
*/});

var line2 = getMultilineString(function () {/*
        return ".NET welcomes " + input.ToString(); 
    }
*/});

//var hello = edge.func(function () {/*
//    async (input) => { 
//        return ".NET welcomes " + input.ToString(); 
//    }
//*/});


var hello = edge.func(line1 + line2);

hello('Node.js', function (error, result) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Ok. It probably works, but it looks soooo ugly, so I'd prefer to have single C# function with switch ... case. Thanks.